# redux-form: How do I dynamically exclude one sync validator?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

My [redux-form](http://redux-form.com/) decorated form component conditionally has an `email` field, depending on my redux state (depending on whether or not the user is a guest.)

I only want to sync-validate that field when it is present (conditionally rendered.) Currently the form's validator includes an `email` field validator, and **this validator runs even when the field has been excluded from the form, during `render`.**

When I "instantiate" the form's validator, *and* when I pass the validator as an argument to the redux-form decorator, state isn't known. So I'm currently unable to decide whether to include the `email` field validator, in either of these places.

What's the best way to dynamically include / exclude a single field's redux-form validator, at "runtime" / "validation time", based on state?

**MyForm.js**

```js
import validate from './MyFormValidator';

// [form class whose render optionally shows the email component]

export default reduxForm(
  {
    form: 'myForm',
    fields,
    validate
  }
)(MyForm)
```

**MyFormValidator.js**

```js
import {createValidator, required, email} from '../../utils/validation';

export default createValidator({
  email: [email],
  country: [required],
  // ...
});
```

**utils/validation.js**

```js
export function email(value) {
  const emailRegex = /.../i;
  if (!emailRegex.exec(value)) {
    return 'Please provide a valid email address.';
  }
}

export function required(value, message) {
  if (isEmpty(value)) {
    return message || 'Required.';
  }
}

export function createValidator(rules) {
  return (data = {}) => {
    const errors = {};
    Object.keys(rules).forEach((key) => {
      const rule = join([].concat(rules[key]));
      const error = rule(data[key], data);
      if (error) {
        errors[key] = error;
      }
    });
    return errors;
  };
}
```

My sync validation is modeled after this implementation, linked to from the 4.2.0 redux-form docs (I'm using 5.3.1): https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/utils/validation.js

Comment: Opened an issue for this on the redux-form GitHub: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1514

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@lewiscowper](https://twitter.com/lewiscowper) who suggested this solution on some JavaScript Slack.

Since the input is a text field, the value will come through as an empty string if the input was rendered.

**So if `value` is `null`/`undefined`, we can skip validation for the field, since we know it wasn't rendered.**

To avoid false-positive usages of the validator, I renamed it `emailUnlessNull`.

```js
export function emailUnlessNull(value) {
  // Don't validate the text field if it's value is undefined (if it wasn't included in the form)
  if (value == null) {
    return;
  }
  const emailRegex = /.../i;
  if (!emailRegex.exec(value)) {
    return 'Please provide a valid email address.';
  }
}
```

In the end I think a solution that totally excludes the validator --- and doesn't complicate the validator's logic and it's usage --- would be much better, but for now this works.

Happy to accept a better answer.

**EDIT:**

You also have to make sure that, **in the optional-field-render scenario, you also trigger it's value to be an empty string.** Before it's been touched, its value comes through the validator as null.

**MyForm.js**

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  const { values, fields, isGuestOrder } = this.props;

  if (isGuestOrder && values.email == null) {
    fields.email.onChange('');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consider [React-Redux-Form](https://github.com/davidkpiano/react-redux-form), this is already built-in:

```jsx
import { Field } from 'react-redux-form';
import { required, email } from '../../utils/validation';

// inside render():
<Field model="user.email"
  errors={{ email }}
/>
```

Two things will happen:

- The error validators (in `error`) will run on every change. You can set `validateOn="blur"` to modify this behavior.
- Validation will only occur if the `<Field>` is rendered. If the `<Field>` is unmounted, validation will be reset for that field.